# Uploading many json files at once using Curl and a website API

Tags: json, curl

I have multiple JSON files within a folder and I would like to post them all at once, in a single command line using curl. Is there a way ?

I have these files in a folder

```
1.json
2.json
3.json
4.json
5.json
```

... and more

I'd like to post all of the files from the folder in one go.

I know how to post one file :

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://api.nft-maker.io/UploadNft/ApiKey/ID' \
  -H 'accept: text/plain' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"assetName": "GhostCastle999", "previewImageNft": {"mime_Type": "png", "description": "Casper", "fileFromIPFS": "QmNuFre999.png", "metadataPlaceholder": [{"": ""}]}}'
```

but i'm stuck on how to upload a 5k json files and is this code supports multiple posting ? please help.

Answer (score 0):

use **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** like following

```
curl -X POST https://api.nft-maker.io/UploadNft/ApiKey/ID
   -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
   -d "file1=eyJhc3NldE5hbWUiOiAiR2hvc3RDYXN0bGU5OTkiLCAicHJldmlld0ltYWdlTmZ0IjogeyJtaW1lX1R5cGUiOiAicG5nIiwgImRlc2NyaXB0aW9uIjogIkNhc3BlciIsICJmaWxlRnJvbUlQRlMiOiAiUW1OdUZyZTk5OS5wbmciLCAibWV0YWRhdGFQbGFjZWhvbGRlciI6IFt7IiI6ICIifV19fQ==&file2=value2&file3=value3&file4=value4&file5=value5"
```

and make a base64encoding of each json and put it as field value then on the receiving end take each field apart and save

or you have to call the follwing for each json

```
curl -X POST https://api.nft-maker.io/UploadNft/ApiKey/ID
   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
   -d '{"assetName": "GhostCastle999", "previewImageNft": {"mime_Type": "png", "description": "Casper", "fileFromIPFS": "QmNuFre999.png", "metadataPlaceholder": [{"": ""}]}}'
```

Comment: when running a base64encoding of one json file i get this `{
    "resultState": 1,
    "errorMessage": "Invalid JSON Data submitted",
    "errorCode": 99
}`

Comment: please put the code used as it seems data submitted was invalid. BTW please keep in mind if you are going to use base64 encoding you need to decode the string at the receiving end.